# Malware that renames graphic files

Tags: windows-10, virus, malware

Recently I noticed that something in my system changes the image filenames (.png, .jpg, .gif etc.) to offsenive pornographic names but not changes the files itself.

Filenames changed only in my home directory.

Only I have access to pc and files aren't accessible over a network

I use Windows 10 Home x64 and AVG Free Antyvirus. I also used Malwarebytes, AdwCleaner SuperAntiSpyware and HitmanPro. I scanned the system but nothing was found (only some Cookie.Tracking stuff). ProcessExplorer does not show anything suspicious.

Now I don't even know if this malware still stucks in my system. The last modification of the file whose name was changed is 11.06.17 8.20pm.

Comment: Does anybody else might had access to your pc? As no actual damage is done, it more seems to be a trolling than a malware.

Comment: The screen shots whilst accurate and show off your issue are offensive due to the wording (pornographic), and anyone of any age can use this website. I don't feel that the images are required (I think the wording you have is adequate) and so I've removed them!

Comment: Only I have access to pc and files aren't accessible over a network

Comment: Is there a way to check which process modified the file in Windows?

Comment: Those non-English dirty words are Polish. Maybe this will give somebody a clue.